# Injectivity of mapping of an $A$-module $M$ into $M_B$, where $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Suppose that $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra, where $A$ is a commutative ring. I would like to show that iv) $\Rightarrow$ v), where iv) and v) are as follows :

iv) If $M$ is any non-zero $A$-module, then $M_B \neq 0$.

v) For every $A$-module $M$, the mapping $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x$ of $M$ into $M_B$ is injective.

I've started a proof (shown below) that I'd like to finish :

We will show that iv) $\Rightarrow$ v) by the contrapositive. Suppose that v) is false. That is, suppose that there exists an $A$-module $M$ such that the mapping $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x$ of $M$ into $M_B$ is not injective. Then the kernel of this mapping is not trivial, so there exists a non-zero $x \in M$ such that $1 \otimes x = 0$ in $M_B$. Since the inclusion map $\iota:Ax \hookrightarrow M$ is injective and $B$ is a flat $A$-module, the map $\iota \otimes 1: Ax \otimes_A B \rightarrow M \otimes_A B = M_B$ is injective.

How can I finish this proof ? We need to show that iv) is false to finish the proof by contrapositive. To do this, my idea was to show that $(Ax)_B = Ax \otimes_A B = 0$, since $Ax$ is a non-zero $A$-module.

Edit : If I can show that $\text{Im}(\iota \otimes 1)$ is zero, then I believe that I am done.

Thanks !

Comment: That $x$ is in the kernel of $M \rightarrow M \otimes_A B$ implies that the elementary tensor $x \otimes b \in Ax \otimes_A B$ maps to $0$ in $M \otimes_A B$.  (Write $x \otimes b = b ( x \otimes 1)$, using the $B$-module structure of $M \otimes_A B$, and you know $x \otimes 1 = 0$).  Since $Ax \otimes_A B \rightarrow M \otimes_A B$ is injective, this shows that $Ax \otimes_A B = 0$.  By assumption of (iv), $Ax = 0$, i.e. $M \rightarrow M \otimes_A B$ has trivial kernel = is injective.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Are you showing that $\text{Im}(\iota \otimes 1) = 0$ ? If so, why does it suffice to just show that the elementary tensor $x \otimes b \in Ax \otimes_A B$ maps to $0$ ? Shouldn't we check that every tensor product in $Ax \otimes_A B$ maps to $0$ ?

Comment: What does an arbitrary element of $Ax \otimes_A B$ look like?  $\sum (a_i x \otimes b_i) = \sum (x \otimes a_i b_i) = x \otimes \sum a_i b_i$

Comment: In other words, every element of $Ax \otimes_A B$ is represented by an elementary tensor.  This should not be surprising.  $Ax$ is a cyclic module.  A cyclic module $N$ is always isomorphic to $A / \operatorname{Ann}_A(N)$, so $Ax \otimes_A B \cong A/\operatorname{Ann}_A(x) \otimes_A B \cong B/\operatorname{Ann}_A(x)B$

Comment: But yes more importantly, as you say, any element of a tensor product is a sum of elementary tensors, so we can focus on those.  In this case you also happen to be looking at a cyclic module in which every element is represented by an elementary tensor!!